# How to handle a quote character in a quoted csv column using python and pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file similar to the below. I am reading it using python pandas.

> ```
> "Col1","Col2","Col3","Col4","Col5"
> "XXX","1234","asdf " asdf, asdf","1","1234"
> "XXX","1234","asdf asdf, asdf","1","1234"
> ```

```
df = pd.read_csv(BytesIO(content),quotechar = '"')
```

The problem is with the quote and comma in between the quoted field `"asdf " asdf, asdf"`

The data has five columns, but due to the nature of the first data line the `read_csv` function keeps seeing 6 columns.

How can I fix this string using python so pandas can read it properly

**Update**
This works... not elegant but sufficient.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import BytesIO

with open('C:\\Users\\test\\Desktop\\test.csv') as f:
    content = f.read()

content = content[0].replace('"','&&&') + \
          content.replace('","','|||')[1:].replace('\n"','\n&&&').replace('"\n','&&&\n')[:-1] + \
          content[-1].replace('"','&&&')

content = content.replace('"',' ').replace(',',' ').replace("|||",'","').replace('&&&','"')

#print content

df = pd.read_csv(BytesIO(content),quotechar = '"')
print df
```

Comment: No, can't reproduce on 0.22.

Comment: i needed to correct the above example... it is one quote in between the quoted field. not two.

Comment: So, correct it in your question?

Comment: just did it....

Comment: Hmm, this still works for me, giving 6 columns. v0.22.

Comment: What is your result and what is the expected results? I got this: `Columns: [a, 1, Unnamed: 2, textmoretext", Unnamed: 4, 1.0]`.  Are you expecting it to remove all the quotes? Or expect to see `text"moretext` instead? Also v0.22.

Comment: updated question. More precise.

Comment: Can you just use `error_bad_lines=True` to ignore them? I don't believe pandas can fix/read it correctly.

Comment: yeah maybe... tried to solve it.. .see my solution